# Update/Add Json file Key value pair without updating the file

Tags: python, json

```
 {
                "app": {
                    "Garden": {
                        "Flowers": {
                            "Red flower": "Rose",
                            "White Flower": "Jasmine",
                            "Yellow Flower": "Marigold"
                        }
                    },
                    "Fruits": {
                        "Yellow fruit": "Mango",
                        "Green fruit": "Guava",
                        "White Flower": "groovy"
                    },
                    "Trees": {
                        "label": {
                            "Yellow fruit": "Pumpkin",
                            "White Flower": "Bogan"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have a file with JSON content as shown above,I wanted to add/override the Key-value pair in this file without touching the existing lines in the file. Reason being when I upload the file to git it shows me the entire file has been changed and not just the updated Key-value pair. My problem is when i open the file and write to it the entire file is getting updated.

Say for example i want to update:

```
json[app][Garden][Flowers][Red Flower] = 'Shoe Flower'
```

Only this above Key-Value pair should be updated in the Json file and not the entire file should be re-written.

This is not working:

```
with open("/Users/vbabu/Documents/sk-SK.json",'a/w') as json_data:
    json.dump(pte,json_data,ensure_ascii=False,indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why has the whole file changed? Probably because the formatting of the original file doesn't match what is auto-generated by `json.dump`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the wrong concept about modify file.

Update one line means you made a new file and replace the old file.

Git shown that whole file changed may because of the line-indent.

You set `json.dump indent=4`, you file may be not match the formatted json.

If you do not want to format you file, you should try string operate and write content instead of json.dump.